# Migrating to Cloud Endpoints Framework v2, iOS Client

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

My Google App Engine application uses the old (v1) version of the Cloud Endpoints, as far as I see in the documentation it is recommended to migrate to v2 **Cloud Endpoints Framework**.

The application uses Java Standard Environment and it is a backend for Android and iOS clients.

Currently during development of the API I generate both the client libraries for Android and the discovery docs for the iOS mobile application, as described in the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/generate-discovery-doc-ios

The documentation of the v2 version does however read **only about generating the Android client library**.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks

So my question is:

Does the new version of the Cloud Endpoints feature support generating the discovery docs, or helps to integrate the iOS Client in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the new Endpoints can still generate discovery documents. However, you must upgrade to the [new RESTful iOS client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest), as the old one has been deprecated for almost a year. Using the `EndpointsTool` main class, you can pass arguments `get-discovery-doc com.example.TestEndpoint...` to get a discovery document. Then, follow the instructions on the REST client page. We will eventually have docs for this, apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? My cloud endpoints project is in Android Studio and I can't seem to figure out how to generate the discovery docs.

Comment: In the deprecated v1(google cloud endpoint framework), for generating the IOS client library, the doc says - The Endpoints command line tool can generate a discovery document in either REST format (the default) or RPC format (required for generating an iOS client). Should we generate the discovery doc for REST format or RPC format?

Comment: Github link in "new RESTful iOS client" says - "Add the library's source folders to the Header Search Paths entry of your project's build settings: Source, Source/Objects, Source/Utilities, Deps/gtm-session-fetcher/Source". I am not sure how to do this. Can you please explain?